# Recargar la información de una tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery

Estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto, y tengo una tabla que se llena dinámicamente con información de una base de datos, a través de Ajax.

La información de esta tabla, es la información de los productos y sus respectivas cantidades que serán añadidas en una factura.

Tengo un botón "Agregar" que manda la información del producto y su cantidad a la base de datos, y el conjunto de esa información es la que se retorna a la tabla.

Lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna manera de que solo se recargue la información de la tabla al momento de agregar un nuevo producto a esta, ya que la única forma de que se me actualice la información es recargando totalmente la pagina, y me gustaría evitar esta situación.

Esta es la tabla donde mando a llamar esa información:

```
<table class="table table-striped mt-3">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Codigo del Producto</th>
      <th class="text-center">Descripcion</th>
      <th class="text-center">Precio Unitario</th>
      <th class="text-center">Cantidad</th>
      <th class="text-center">Precio Total</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody-tabla-temp">

      </tbody>
      </table>
```

Esta es la funcionalidad del boton agregar:

```
$('#btn-agregar-producto-detalle-temp').click(function(){

    var parametros = "idProducto=" + $('#slc-productos-factura').val() + "&&" + "cantidad=" + $('#cantidad-producto-factura').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/api.php?accion=agregar-producto-tabla-temporal",
        method: "POST",
        data: parametros,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(respuesta){
            alert('Producto añadido exitosamente');
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
});
```

Y este es el ajax donde mando a llamar toda la información:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/api.php?accion=ver-productos-tabla-temporal",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(respuesta){
        for(var i=0;i<respuesta.length;i++){
            var totalProducto = (respuesta[i].precioVenta * respuesta[i].cantidad);

            $('#tbody-tabla-temp').append(
                '<tr>'+
                '<th class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].idProducto+'</th>'+
                '<th class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].nombre+'</th>'+
                '<th class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].precioVenta+'</th>'+
                '<th class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].cantidad+'</th>'+
                '<th class="text-center">'+totalProducto.toFixed(2)+'</th>'+
                '<th class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
                 onClick="eliminarProductoTemp('+respuesta[i].idProducto+')">Eliminar</button></th>'+
                '</tr>'
            );
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu función agregar después de :

```
alert('Producto añadido exitosamente');<br>
```

Coloca todo tu ajax de listado en una funcion `list_table();`

y lo llamas después de agregar:

```
alert('Producto añadido exitosamente');
list_table();
```

Comment: Intente realizar tu propuesta, pero al momento de que quiero agregar otro produto, se vuelve a repetir el primero. Lo interesante es que si recargo la pagina, solo me aparecen los dos productos y no me aparece el primero repetido